# What is the proper way to animate an array of objects with react-native-reanimated, considering a sub-component is not an option?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-native-reanimated, react-native-reanimated-v2

I am trying to use the `react-native-reanimated` v2 to animate an array of `Animated.View`s.

For my case, there are 2 handicaps:

1. The objects will eventually animate each other. Because of this I am not able to generate a new sub-component for each draggable object. (If I try to do so, signaling between sub-components probably will be a hell.)
2. The [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) forbids the usage of the hooks within loops or other functions. (But that is what I need as far as I see.)

I made a snack to give the idea about what I try to achieve here (please note, one of the boxes is able to move another one here):
https://snack.expo.dev/@mehmetkaplan/react-native-reanimated-array-animation

But I guess because of the above item 2, the snack does not behave consistent, sometimes the drag does not respond. (The [single box version](https://snack.expo.dev/@mehmetkaplan/react-native-reanimated_and_react-native-gesture-handler) of the snack has a much more smooth response.)

Coming back to the main question. What is the proper way to animate an array of objects with `react-native-reanimated`, considering a sub-component is not an option?

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: What list behavior do you want to achieve? This info would open a room for alternative implementation ideas

Comment: Same one in the provided snacks.

Comment: Regarding the respond, it's probably because in the second case you are wrapping the entire View, and in the second only the text. In fact, in this regard, it works fine, but was it planned this way? Or is there no problem wrapping the entire View component? As I understand it, you want to achieve the behavior from the first snack, but you want to understand how it is better to arrange it (for example, to avoid somehow loops and nested hooks), but you don’t want to move this logic to subcomponents, since there is a common logic between some elements. Did I understand correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Using hooks in loop

Definitely not something to be proud of but it'll be all right as long as the order of `use...` calls remains unaffected and all logic happens after the calls. This means during the lifecycle of the component, **the number of iterations in the loop should not change**.

Basically the order in which all hooks are called should always be the same.

##### Inconsistent behaviour

Make sure your `PanGestureHandler` wraps `Animated.View` component otherwise it'll not work on mobile devices.

Apart from weird drag handle (only working from `Text`) and breaking on mobile devices. I couldn't spot any inconsistency in the behaviour. Nesting the whole `Animated.View` inside `PanGestureHandler` fixes both issues,

```
<PanGestureHandler onGestureEvent={gestureHandlers[i]}>
  <Animated.View style={[styles.box, animatedStyles[i]]} key={`View-${i}`}>
      <Text style={{color: "#FFFF00", fontWeight:'bold'}}>{`I am the box #${i}\nDrag Me${i === 1 ? "(I move also Box 0)" : ""}`}</Text>
  </Animated.View>
</PanGestureHandler>
```

Here is a working example,

https://snack.expo.dev/A9IF7ngoC

Comment: Yes it seams the wrapping was the issue. I guess we can close this @shramee.